# How can I test my own image on my CNN model?

Tags: conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I'm a beginner programmer trying out image classification using CNN. I'm aiming to build a model which classifies if an image is an aluminum can or not, and I want to test it with my own image.

I've resized the images with the code below:

#Resizing to 128,128
files = os.listdir("../input/aluminum-can-image-data/Aluminum Cans")

for f in files:
img = Image.open("../input/aluminum-can-image-data/Aluminum Cans/" + f)
img = img.resize((128,128))

ds_train_ = image_dataset_from_directory(
'../input/aluminum-can-image-data',
labels='inferred',
image_size=[128, 128],
interpolation='nearest',
batch_size=64,
)
ds_valid_ = image_dataset_from_directory(
'../input/aluminum-can-image-data',
labels='inferred',
image_size=[128, 128],
interpolation='nearest',
batch_size=64,
)

ds_train, ds_valid = train_test_split(files, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

I want to build a code which shows the percentage of how likely an image is an aluminum can when it has received a single image. Any help with the codes to build this function would be highly appreciated~!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please edit your post and place all of the code in your question inside the code-block feature provided in your post editor.  You can do this easily by highlighting the code and then clicking on the `{ }` tag above the editor

Answer (score 0):

let us suppose the model you use is named "model" and you have has 2 ouput labels -"Aluminium","Not Aluminium" .

As you only need the prediction of only a single image, you have to use np.expandims(image,axis=0) to increase the dimension for the input for the model to work.

##### Code:

`class=["alum","not_alum"]`

`prediction=model.predict(np.expand_dims(image,axis=0))`

`confidence=round(100 * (np.max(prediction[0]),2)`

`argclass=np.argmax(prediction,axis=1)`

`print(class[argclass[0])`

`print(confidence)` .

Comment: thanks for the answer! Well there's one more thing I want to ask... my model is a regression model, so I want the result to be in a form of percentage (ex. 80% possibility of aluminum can)
Can you give me help on that too